# Calculate elements dimensions in order to fit inside container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an ul with fixed width 235px and height 200px. This ul is populated by n numbers of li depending on a query results. How can I calculate the dimensions of the li in order for them to fill all the available space inside the ul.

I have tried calculating the container's perimeter and comparing it with  the total of each element's perimeter but that doesn't work.

Comment: Must all the li elements be the same dimensions?

Comment: yes, they must be the same dimension

Comment: Assuming that the li elements must not overlap, then it's impossible to fill ALL the available space if they must all be the same dimensions. My guess is that you want to work out the li size required to fill as much as possible of the 235x200 space? Must the li elements be exactly square? Do the elements for `n` items need to be the same shape as for `n+1`?

Comment: Additional: It's possible to cover the ul completely in the trivial case of each li being 200px high and (235/n)px wide, or 235px wide and (200/n)px high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's my attempt at code that will work out a fairly high coverage of the `ul` (not sure if it's actually maximal), given the constraints that the `li`s need not be square,  but must all be the same size for any given number of items.

The first part gives a function `getSquare(n)` which will memoize the generation of squares, so that if you need to use it multiple times on a page it won't keep recalculating things.

The second part is the function that does the calculation. Pass it the number of items, and the width and height of your container, and it will return an object with width and height properties for the items. It doesn't ensure integer results.

The line with the throw is just there for testing purposes really, could be removed.

```
var getSquare = (function()
{
    var squares = [];
    return function(n)
    {
        if (!squares[n])
        {
            squares[n] = Math.pow(n, 2);
        }
        return squares[n];
    };
})();


function calcItemDimensions(itemCount, areaWidth, areaHeight)
{
    var x, y, slots,
        n = 0,
        sq = 0;

    while (itemCount > sq)
    {
        n += 1;
        sq = getSquare(n);
    }

    x = y = n;
    slots = sq;

    while (slots - itemCount >= x)
    {
        if (x === y) { y -= 1; }
        else { x = y; }
        slots = x * y;
        if (slots < itemCount) { throw new Error('slots < itemCount: ' + slots + ' < ' + itemCount); }
    }

    return { width: areaWidth / x, height: areaHeight / y };
}
```

Comment: `var x = y = n` is a valid syntactic shorthand for the latter. Either works :)

Comment: ...sure, but it defines `y` globally ;)

Comment: Oooh, so it does. I never noticed that before. Serves me right for trusting stuff on the internet. Thanks @yckart for teaching me something. I shall edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make ul height dynamic according to number of li and apply css display:inline-block and overflow: hidden to ul

Comment: I can't do that I want the li resided to fit the available fixed height and width

Answer (score 0):

Do not mention width for `li` at all

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap{
    width:235px;
    height:200px;
    background:grey
}
ul{background:red; margin:0; padding:0; width:100%;}
li{
    display:inline-block;  
    margin-right:2px;
    background:red;
    border-right:solid black green; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hfQhv/2/)**

---

**CASE 2**

Add `height:100%` to li (it force li to cove the entire available height) and give the same bg color for both `ul & li` so that it looks like it has occupied the available width

```
html,body{height:100%}
ul{
   background:red; 
   margin:0; padding:0; 
   width:235px;
   height:200px;
}
li{
    display:inline-block;   height:100%;
    margin-right:2px;
    background:green;
    border-right:solid black green; 
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/hfQhv/3/)**

Comment: the ul is the wrapper and I need the li to take the maximum available height and width so all of them can fit inside the ul

Comment: @FlorianShena you mean width:235px is for ul??

Comment: that does not help either. What I need, as shown in your example, is for the li be in a grid style.

Answer (score 0):

You might do this with jQuery if you want to.

something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var liCount = parseInt($('ul li').length());
   var height = parseInt($('ul').height();
   var liHeight = height / liCount;
   $('ul li').css('height', liHeight);
});
```

An ofcourse, Don't forget to give the ul and ID and pass this into jQuery instead of 'ul li', otherwise all li object in your page will be affected

Comment: Nope, tried it, does not do the job, the elements do not fill all the container, they become too small