# Calculate child dimensions to always fit inside container, regardless of the number of child items

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid

I have a grid of child elements, all perfectly square, that need to fit inside of a container as perfectly as possible. The container size can change in both width and height, and the number of items inside the container can also change dynamically.

I need to be able to set sizes on the child items within the container in order to form a grid as close to perfect as possible.

I've had a try at various solutions, including this (accepted) one from another stackoverflow question: [Calculate elements dimensions in order to fit inside container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644903/calculate-elements-dimensions-in-order-to-fit-inside-container)

As well as attempting to tackle the problem using a variety of media-queries, though this limits me in what I am able to do (elements get cut off with overflow: hidden) and so isn't a viable solution.

```css
.container {
   border: 1px solid blue;
   height: 400px;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 602px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item" style="height:200px; width: 200px;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="height:200px; width: 200px;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="height:200px; width: 200px;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="height:200px; width: 200px;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="height:200px; width: 200px;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="height:200px; width: 200px;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="height:200px; width: 200px;"></div>
</div>
```

I'd like to update the `height` and `width` attributes on each child element.

Comment: please add some examples and your tries

Comment: does the childs have the same size?

Comment: _"I've had a try at various solutions"_ Can you include `html`, `css` , `js` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, the child elements all need to be perfectly square. I know it's impossible to get the elements to fill the area perfectly, but as perfectly as possible is what I'm after.

Comment: sorry, i did not get it, does all of the squares have the same size?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, all squares are the same size.

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate?